# How to change from arraylist to class [ ]?

Tags: java, android

I would like to assign the string-type data in my list to an object in a class. I tried for loop, but I couldn't create it, I can't do it directly. How can I solve this problem?

**CheckModel.class**

```
public class CheckModel {
    private String name;
    private boolean isSelected;

    public CheckModel(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }}
```

**xFragment.java class**

ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();

```
..
for loop
list2.add("...");
..

getCheckModel(list2);


private CheckModel[] getCheckModel(ArrayList<String> list)
    {

//How do I make the assignment here?

        return checkModels;
    }
```

Comment: `ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();` **Warning:** you're using raw types. Never do that, always provide type arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want this

```
private CheckModel[] getCheckModel(ArrayList<CheckModel> list)
{
    return list.toArray(new CheckModel[list.size()]);
}
```

### Edit

First create an `ArrayList<CheckModel>` as :

```
private ArrayList<CheckModel> mList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then do a for loop to create items on that list :

```
for(int i = 0; i<=10; i++){
  mList.add(new CheckModel("Name "+i,(i%2==0 ? true : false));
}
```

Or if you want add them manually :

```
mList.add(new CheckModel("Example 1", true);
mList.add(new CheckModel("Example 2", false);
```

Then change your method to :

```
private CheckModel[] getCheckModel(ArrayList<CheckModel> list)
{
  return list.toArray(new CheckModel[list.size()]);
}
```

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'getCheckModel'

Comment: Edited the answer, was a typo

Comment: app has stopped. I tried it but it didn't work. Again I tried again did not work.

Comment: Try it with my new edit, please, aslo pase your full code please

Comment: Thanks, man, I've been trying to solve it since yesterday. Finally.

Comment: You welcome, if it helped to you and you think this is the correct one mark it as a correct (The green icon) thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically same idea as other answers but why not add to the CheckModel class since it is a form of construction:

```
public static CheckModel[] getAll (ArrayList<String> list) {
    ArrayList<CheckModel> result = new ArrayList<CheckModel>();
    for (String s : list) {
        // assume isSelected is false
        result.add(new CheckModel(s));
    }
    return result.toArray(new CheckModel[0]);
}
```